# ReferenceError: function is not defined, calling regular function from async function

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await

I'm receiving the following error:

`ReferenceError: processElement is not defined`

When trying to invoke this regular function from my main async function.

I'm using Chrome Puppeteer to get information about page elements. Puppeteer wants to run in an async function, understandably, but I need to do some processing in other functions, possibly recursively.

My basic structure is this:

```
function processElement(element, index) {
  // element processing here, may ultimately need recursion.
}

function async main() {
  // puppeteer stuff
  const elements = document.querySelectorAll('p');
  elements.forEach((element, index) => {
    processElement(element, index);
  }
}

main();
```

Thanks for any help! I'm new to the whole async/await paradigm.

Comment: Can you please post your actual code, not something with a syntax error?

Comment: Are you using Puppeteer to evaluate that code inside the loaded page?

Comment: Puppeteer does not support closures.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `async` keyword before the `function`.

```js
function processElement(element, index) {
  // element processing here, may ultimately need recursion.
  console.log(element);
}

async function main() {
  // puppeteer stuff
  const elements = document.querySelectorAll('p');
  elements.forEach((element, index) => {
    processElement(element, index);
  });
}

main();
```

```html
<p>Hello</p>
<p>World</p>
```